# how to get the next value in influx db

Tags: influxdb

Let me know how can I solve or write query in influx for this scenario ( flux or influx query will work for me )

I have a field called x and m. There is a function in influx called difference which takes the difference between the first and the next field value.
I would like to take the difference between x and next x value and also would like to have the next m value as the row

so this is what I require as a single row
(x_next - x), m_next
.....

How can I do that in influx of flux queries. I can have x_next-x using difference but how to get m_next in this.

Comment: Did you try query like: `select difference(x), last(m) from mydata group by time(1m)` ?  For each 1 minute interval it returns delta for x and last value for m.

Comment: I would like to have the value of the subsequent row and not group by time

Comment: I believe `select difference(x), moving_average(m)+0.5*difference(m) from mydata` is the closest solution you can use without group by time.

Comment: Awesome Yuri, I never thought of this. Please publish this as an answer and I will mark it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select difference(x), moving_average(m)+0.5*difference(m) from mydata
```

is the closest solution you can use without `group by time`.

Comment: It is possible to do the same thing with string values